# PyMongo support for sub-field projections

Tags: python, pymongo

In MongoDB, I can perform [projections](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) on sub-fields. For example, `db.collection.find({},{"field.subfield":1, "_id":0})` will return all documents and show only the specified subfield, and hide any other fields from the output.

PyMongo does [support](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=projection) projections, but doesn't seem to work for sub-fields. An example code is given below.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoDB()
client.db.collection.find(projection=['field1','field2.subfield'])
```

So my questions are: does PyMongo support sub-field projections? If yes, what is the correct syntax to do that?

Comment: You syntax is correct. Please provide an example of document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
client.db.collection.drop()
client.db.collection.insert_one({
    'field1': 1,
    'field2': {
        'subfield': 'sub',
        'othersubfield' : 'othersub'
    }
})

print(list(client.db.collection.find(projection=['field1','field2.subfield'])))
```

This prints:

```
[{u'field2': {u'subfield': u'sub'}, u'field1': 1, u'_id': ObjectId('58e3d11dca1ce936cf6498c4')}]
```

You'll observe that "othersubfield" is *not* included, because it has been omitted from the projection.